# Is there a way for a multiple line (with multiple entry field in each) screen design in Tkinter (or another module) in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

If I want to have a multiple-line screen design (with multiple fields in each), is there a widget or something to achive this in Python?

Say for instance, I will make an inventory item entry screen with 20 lines(or more), in each there will be these fields:

- Item no (char&input capable)
- item name (output only and depending on my input for item no it will be displayed promptly)
- amount (integer&input capable)
- unit(char&input capable)..

I must be able to make data entry or update freely in whichever line I want and when I am done, with a push-button I must be able to save them all..

For such a screen design, is there a standardized way of having a multiple line with multiple entry field facility in Tkinter or another module in Python?

If there is not, how do you design such data entry screens in Python? I still couldn't find it anywhere, so I wanted to open this question here for discussion.. Thank you all..

Comment: There is no ready-made Tkinter widget for this, but you can use the grid layout to create a table of entries / labels.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have a "multiple-line screen design" in tkinter. tkinter can handle almost any type of layout you can imagine. There is no standardized way to do that because no two GUIs are the same.

How do you go about designing such a screen? First, with pencil and paper. The way to implement it would probably be easiest using the [grid geometry manager](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html), though the actual implementation depends on a lot of factors related to exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your replies guys, at the beginning I thought I would need to define 80 entry fields as variables for 20lines&4 fields in each, and said noway! But gridding and the code snippet below which I encountered somewhere put how in a single for loop we can create the whole screen all at once.. and by event handling and getting the row variable where cursor is on we can manage the whole screen and fields, yes its very practical:)

Thanks again for sparing your valuble time:)

```
from Tkinter import *
colours = ['red','green','orange','white','yellow','blue']
r = 0
for c in colours:
    Label(text=c, relief=RIDGE,width=15).grid(row=r,column=0)
    Entry(bg=c, relief=SUNKEN,width=10).grid(row=r,column=1)
    r = r + 1
mainloop()
```